# Complicated lookup - based on specific value in list

Tags: excel, lookup

I need some help in finding a formula that can help do very specific lookups.

I have an accounting spreadsheet with 30,000 rows - an example extract is below:

```
Product Nr. Product Date    Purchase or Sale    Sale TAT
12345   test product 12345  02.06.2014  Purchase    
12345   test product 12345  02.06.2014  Sale    0
12345   test product 12345  30.09.2014  Purchase    
12345   test product 12345  30.09.2014  Sale    0
23456   test product 23456  08.01.2014  Purchase    
23456   test product 23456  20.01.2014  Sale    12
23456   test product 23456  12.06.2014  Purchase    
23456   test product 23456  13.06.2014  Sale    1
23456   test product 23456  30.07.2014  Purchase    
23456   test product 23456  04.08.2014  Purchase    
23456   test product 23456  04.08.2014  Sale    0
56789   test product 56789  07.01.2014  Sale    
56789   test product 56789  13.05.2014  Sale    126
56789   test product 56789  03.12.2014  Sale    204
```

Each row is either a purchase or sale. I need a solution where I can, for each sale, lookup to the previous purchase date - and calculate the difference.

Right now, I just lookup the previous row and compare dates - but of course, this is totally inaccuate - as one purchase may have many sales. I do check if the product nr is the same, but that's all.

Any ideas on how I can say: "for this sale... go back to the last purchase in the list... and use that date."

Thanks!

Comment: Also - does volume matter at all? As in, can you purchase 50 units, then sell 20, then sell another 20, then purchase 30, and then sell another 20? Or are you simply purchasing an identical volume each time, and selling them using... FIFO? LIFO?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the confusion. I mean, for a particular sale, go backwards to you reach the next previous purchase entry. In general, we want to count the time between the purchase and sales. Sometimes we have 1 purchase, followed by 5 sales. Each of those sales needs to refer back to that 1 purchase.

Comment: well, volume is a factor - but then its getting crazy. I didn't plan on creating a whole accounting system (but may end up doing so). SO, essentially, FIFO I guess

Comment: I've worked out how to return the very last item in a list, like this:
INDEX($C$2:$C$33;MAX(--("Purchase"=$D$2:$D$33);--(A2=$A$2:$A$33)*MATCH(ROW($D$2:$D$33);ROW($D$2:$D$33))));""))

but getting not the last, but the previous... is the tricky part!

Comment: FIFO has a minimum requirement of matxhing product ID that you didn't mention there. Since there can be multiple purchases in a day can row numbers be used as a secondary tool?

Comment: thanks... if it helps, I have a test file shared here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/geqkf4s4lcaldi4/test%20of%20TAT%20formula.xlsx?dl=0

I'm open to using any trick to measure between the sale and its last previous purchase!

Comment: This array formula finds the row of the most recent purchase for every Sale: `=IF(E2="Sale",MAX(IF(E$2:E$15="Purchase",IF(C$2:C$15=C2,IF(D$2:D$15<=D2,ROW(E$2:E$15))))),"")` (Confirm with Ctrl+Shift+Enter) It doesn't do anything to factor in volume though, and it will probably take forever with 30K rows

Comment: HI @Kyle  ... many thanks - I had to change the formula to this:
=WENN(D30="Sale";MAX(WENN(D$2:D$33="Purchase";WENN(C$2:C$33=C30;WENN(D$2:D$33<=D30;ZEILE(E$2:E$33)))));"")

so that the columns were correct. In return, it provides the row number... is that correct? Was that the intention?

I'm just trying to get my head around how to use that number to say... OK, now take my sales date, and subtract it from the purchase data highlighted in that row          ... if that makes sense!! :)

Comment: PS. @Kyle, if this is working as I think it is... you are brilliant man, have a beer on me!!

Comment: OH, one last question - is there someway to check validation with the product number, so you only check the dates if its the same product nr?

Comment: Yes it returns the row number, to get the date you can use INDEX(). It checks the product number already, but I think your column headers are different than what I used. Using your sample spreadsheet, and returning the purchase date, looks like this: `INDEX(C$2:C$33, IF(D30="Sale",MAX(IF(D$2:D$33="Purchase",IF(C$2:C$33<=C30,IF(B$2:B$33=B30,ROW(C$2:C$33)-1)))),""))`

Comment: oh @Kyle, you are a genius!!!! Now it does everything :) Perfect!! There is one wierd thing though, if you check the sample file https://www.dropbox.com/s/geqkf4s4lcaldi4/test%20of%20TAT%20formula.xlsx?dl=0 on row 20, for product 33333, there is no purchase, should it should return an error or whatever. But in fact, it returns a date (first on the list). Is there anyway to fix that? I thought the two IF statements would catch this... but for some reason its getting through.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, @Kyle 's answer was basically the solution:

```
INDEX(C$2:C$33, IF(D30="Sale",MAX(IF(D$2:D$33="Purchase",IF(C$2:C$33<=C30,IF(B$2:B$33=B30,ROW(C$‌​2:C$33)-1)))),""))
```

thanks!

Comment: not sure why i was downvoted for posting the answer here. Did I do something wrong?